# Map column lists to dictionary and create new column with padded strings

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nlp

Given this `dataframe` and `word_index` dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'text_ids': [
                                     [1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 0],
                                     [1, 2, 4, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 0],
                                     [1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 8, 2, 0],
                                     [1, 2, 9, 2, 6, 2, 10, 2, 11, 2, 8, 0]
                                    ]})

word_index = {0: '<eos>', 1: '<sos>', 2: '/s', 3: 'he', 4: 'she', 5:'they', 6:'love', 7:'loves', 8: 'cats', 9: 'we', 10: 'talking', 11: 'about', 12: '<pad>'}
```

How can I map each sequence in `text_ids` to its corresponding value(s) in `word_index`, while making sure that `\s` really creates spaces in each string? Also, I need to add `<pad>` tokens to each string that has a length smaller than the largest integer sequence.

Expected output:

```
                                 text_ids                                       text
0             [1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 0]   <sos> he loves cats <eos><pad><pad><pad>
1             [1, 2, 4, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 0]  <sos> she loves cats <eos><pad><pad><pad>
2             [1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 8, 2, 0]  <sos> they love cats <eos><pad><pad><pad>
3  [1, 2, 9, 2, 6, 2, 10, 2, 11, 2, 8, 0]     <sos> we love talking about cats <eos>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `map` to assign the values from your dictionary. Ensure to first replace `'\s'` with `' '`.

Then reshape your dataframe to wide format with `pivot` to ensure the same number of items and `fillna` the missing spots with `"<pad>"`.

Finally aggregate to a string with `apply` and `join` to the original dataframe:

```
word_index[2] = ' '

df2 = df['text_ids'].explode().map(word_index).reset_index()

df.join(
 df2.assign(col=df2.groupby('index').cumcount())
    .pivot('col', 'index', 'text_ids')
    .fillna('<pad>')
    .apply(''.join)
    .rename('text')
)
```

output:

```
                                 text_ids                                       text
0             [1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 0]   <sos> he loves cats <eos><pad><pad><pad>
1             [1, 2, 4, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 0]  <sos> she loves cats <eos><pad><pad><pad>
2             [1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 8, 2, 0]  <sos> they love cats <eos><pad><pad><pad>
3  [1, 2, 9, 2, 6, 2, 10, 2, 11, 2, 8, 0]      <sos> we love talking about cats<eos>
```

Another option using `apply`:

```
word_index[2] = ' '

# padding values
l = df['text_ids'].str.len()
pad = (l.max()-l).mul(pd.Series(['<pre>']*len(l)))

df['text'] = df['text_ids'].apply(lambda s: ''.join(word_index[e] for e in s))+pad
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
(df["text_ids"]
    .explode()
    .map(word_index)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda q: " ".join(q)))
```